# (XSLT) Numbering tags with attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

So I got for example this xhtml file (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqF):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <p>first line</p>
    <p>second line</p>
    <p>third line</p>
    <p>forth line</p>
    <p>fifth line</p>
</body>
```

I want to number the p tags but their value should be considered as an id attribute. I know you could use xsl:number but I only know how to number inside the the nodes:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

   <xsl:template match="body">
       <test>
       <xsl:apply-templates />
       </test>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="p">
        <p><xsl:number/>. <xsl:apply-templates /></p>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But my desired result should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>



<test>
    <p id="1">first line</p>
    <p id="2">second line</p>
    <p id="3">third line</p>
    <p id="4">forth line</p>
    <p id="5">fith line</p>
</test>
```

How do I create an attribute name inside a tag and start numbering the values inside of it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xsl:attribute` here to create the attribute

```
<xsl:template match="p">
 <p>
   <xsl:attribute name="id">
     <xsl:number />
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:apply-templates />
 </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, if you add `strip-space` to your stylesheet, you could make use of `position()`

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="body">
  <test>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </test>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
  <p id="{position()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Without `strip-space` the `xsl:apply-templates` would select the white-space text nodes, which would affect position. Do note that if you had other elements under `body` aside from `p` this would not give you the expected results. You could do `<xsl:apply-templates select="p" />` in this case, but that would assume you wanted to ignore other elements.

Answer (score 2):

As Tim has already shown you, you can use `xsl:attribute` to construct an attribute node and populate its value with `xsl:number`.

However, in XSLT 2 or 3 you can also use the attribute value template approach Tim has shown for using `position()` and instead call your own function that then uses `xsl:number` with the `select` attribute:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">

   <xsl:function name="mf:number">
       <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
       <xsl:number select="$node"/>
   </xsl:function>

   <xsl:template match="body">
       <test>
       <xsl:apply-templates />
       </test>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="p">
       <p id="{mf:number(.)}">
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </p>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/eiZQaEL is a working XSLT 2 example, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqF/1 the same for XSLT 3 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-number).